# why isn't KO creating observable based on the expression?

Tags: knockout.js

With a binding defined like

```
<div data-bind="myBinding: { ... }, enable: isEnable() && isThatEnabled()"></div>
```

during debugging the JS code, when I look at the allBindings in myBinding's init which is defined like usually :

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext)
```

I see `allBindings.enable` is a boolean value, it's the actual computed value of `isEnable() && isThatEnabled()`. It's not an observable like I would have expected KO to create based on the boolean expression.

My question is why isn't it an observable?

Is it possible to observe the 'enable' binding from `myBinding` in this case?

I see 3 options:

1. define a custom `enable` binding:

   `<div data-bind="myBinding: { ... }, myEnable: isEnable() && isThatEnabled()"></div>`
2. have a 'enable' parameter for `myBinding`:

   `<div data-bind="myBinding: { enable: isEnable() && isThatEnabled() }"></div>`
3. use a computed observable in HTML:

   `data-bind="myBinding: bar, enable: ko.computed(function () { return foo() && foo2(); })"`

The 2nd one seem most reasonable to me.

```js
var model = {
    foo: ko.observable(true),
    foo2: ko.observable(true),
    bar: ko.observable(1)
};

ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
        
    element.innerHTML += ko.isObservable(allBindings().enable);
    
    // how unfortunate, 'enable' binding value is not observable
    // how to listen to 'enable' binding changes right here?
  },

  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
  }
};

function onload() {
  ko.applyBindings(model);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: foo">
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: foo2">
   <button data-bind="myBinding: bar, enable: foo() && foo2()">Is 'enable' binding observable: </button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of `ko` do you use? I can't reproduce this with `ko-3.3.0`. Unexpectedly even works with plain js functions! My sandbox: http://jsbin.com/cituzifuca/edit

Answer (score 1):

From ko source:

```
// Use of allBindings as a function is maintained for backwards compatibility, but its use is deprecated
function allBindings() {
    return ko.utils.objectMap(bindingsUpdater ? bindingsUpdater() : bindings, evaluateValueAccessor);
}
// The following is the 3.x allBindings API
allBindings['get'] = function(key) {
    return bindings[key] && evaluateValueAccessor(getValueAccessor(key));
};
allBindings['has'] = function(key) {
    return key in bindings;
};
```

If you call `allBindings()` it unwraps value of all bindings. So if you access it from computed function (for example from `update` method of your binding), computed function will subscribe to updates of all bindings changes.

You can't access directly observable, but you can wrap it with `ko.computed`:

```
var enableObs = ko.computed(function() {return allBindings().enable;});
```

**NOTE:** use allBindings *as function* is deprecated! Because if you call it from `update` method, it will executes on any update in other bindings. So it is better to:

```
var enableObs = ko.computed(function() {return allBindings.get('enable');});
```

See the difference in the behavior of `myBinding` and `myBinding2`.
Also you can subscribe for updates from `update` method without computed (myBinding3).

```js
var model = {
    foo: ko.observable(true),
    foo2: ko.observable(true),
    text: ko.observable("changeme"),
    log: ko.observableArray([])
};

ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var num=0;
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
        
    var enableObs = ko.computed(function() {
      // Note this computed executes on update of any binding. Not only for `enable` binding. Increment for show it.
      return allBindings().enable.toString() + num++;
    });
    enableObs.subscribe(function() {
      // if you remove counter from computed function this function will execute only on `enable` binding updates.
      element.innerHTML = ko.unwrap(enableObs).toString();
    });
  }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding2 = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var num=0;
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
        
    var enableObs = ko.computed(function() {
      return allBindings.get("enable").toString() + num++;
    });
    enableObs.subscribe(function() {
      element.innerHTML = ko.unwrap(enableObs).toString();
    });
  }
};

var tmp = 0;
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding3 = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {     
      element.innerHTML = allBindings.get('enable').toString() + tmp++;
  }
};

function onload() {
  ko.applyBindings(model);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: text, valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: foo">
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: foo2">
   <button data-bind="myBinding, enable: foo() && foo2(), value: text()">Do smth</button>
  <button data-bind="myBinding2, enable: foo() && foo2(), value: text()">Do smth</button>
  <button data-bind="myBinding3, enable: foo() && foo2(), value: text()">Do smth</button>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**OLD:**

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext)
```

If you want subscription - use `update` function instead.
See example: http://jsbin.com/foxezidada/edit

And docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

> My question is why isn't it an observable?

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js

```
var getValueAccessor = bindingsUpdater
    ? function(bindingKey) {
        return function() {
            return evaluateValueAccessor(bindingsUpdater()[bindingKey]);
        };
    } : function(bindingKey) {
        return bindings[bindingKey];
    };
```

It evalutes here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question? Please see my example. I'm looking into observing 'enable' binding from my custom binding. Is this possible?